# How to reference a custom field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using mssql and am having trouble using a subquery. The real query is quite complicated, but it has the same structure as this:

```
select 
  customerName, 
  customerId,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from Purchases 
    where Purchases.customerId=customerData.customerId
  ) as numberTransactions
from customerData
```

And what I want to do is order the table by the number of transactions, but when I use

```
order by numberTransactions
```

It tells me there is no such field. Is it possible to do this? Should I be using some sort of special keyword, such as `this`, or `self`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the field number, in this case:

```
order by 3
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to do it if your query changes in the future.  It's almost always better to be explicit about your choices than implicit based on ordinality

Comment: I agree with JPunyon. It really reduces readability and can cause confusion when you/someone else goes to read the code later on.

Comment: Its not ideal, but there doesn't seem to be any other way to do it without copying over the logic, and duplicating code, or using a join

Comment: I believe the solution proposed by Nathan B works very well. Doesn't require you to copy over the logic, duplicate code, or use a join :)

Comment: I agree.  This isn't the best solution, it's just the quickest to write.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes you have to wrestle with SQL's syntax (expected scope of clauses)

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
select
  customerName,
  customerId,
  (
    select count(*)
    from Purchases
    where Purchases.customerId=customerData.customerId
  ) as numberTransactions
from customerData
) as sub
order by sub.numberTransactions
```

Also, a solution using JOIN is correct.  Look at the query plan, SQL Server should give identical plans for both solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Do an inner join.  It's much easier and more readable.

```
select 
customerName,
customerID,
count(*) as numberTransactions
from
    customerdata c inner join purchases p on c.customerID = p.customerID
group by customerName,customerID
order by numberTransactions
```

EDIT:  Hey Nathan,

You realize you can inner join this whole table as a sub right?

```
Select T.*, T2.*
From T inner join 
(select 
customerName,
customerID,
count(*) as numberTransactions
from
    customerdata c inner join purchases p on c.customerID = p.customerID
group by customerName,customerID
) T2 on T.CustomerID = T2.CustomerID
order by T2.numberTransactions
```

Or if that's no good you can construct your queries using temporary tables (#T1 etc)

Comment: An innerjoin would be easier in the case of the example. But the actual query I am working on is already using an inner join with another table, so it really has to be a subquery

Answer (score 2):

***There are better ways to get your result but just from your example query this will work on SQL2000 or better.***

If you wrap your alias in single ticks **'numberTransactions'** and then call **ORDER BY 'numberTransactions'**

```
select
  customerName, 
  customerId,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from Purchases 
    where Purchases.customerId=customerData.customerId
  ) as 'numberTransactions'
from customerData
ORDER BY 'numberTransactions'
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing could be achieved by using `GROUP BY` and a `JOIN`, and you'll be rid of the subquery. This might be faster too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in SQL2005, but not SQL2000.

Answer (score -1):

You need to duplicate your logic. SQL Server isn't very smart at columns that you've named but aren't part of the dataset in your FROM statement.

So use

```
select 
  customerName, 
  customerId,
  (
    select count(*) 
    from Purchases p
    where p.customerId = c.customerId
  ) as numberTransactions
from customerData c
order by (select count(*) from purchases p where p.customerID = c.customerid)
```

Also, use aliases, they make your code easier to read and maintain. ;)