# Using a custom field in WHERE clause of SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

My question is very similar to this one [How to reference a custom field in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89820/how-to-reference-a-custom-field-in-sql) I have the following query:

```
SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( id ) 
FROM cms_store_items
WHERE speaker = cms_store_items_speakers.id
) AS count
FROM cms_store_items_speakers
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I need to add a WHERE clause that looks like `WHERE count > 0` but when I do I get the error `Unknown column 'count' in 'where clause'` is there anyway for me to reference the custom field in my where clause without duplicating logic?

I could just place the logic for the where clause in my code but I don't want to send what may well be more then 1000 rows to the app if not needed, it just seems like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, to do this strictly the way you're doing it:

```
select
*
from
(
    SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( id ) 
    FROM cms_store_items
    WHERE speaker = cms_store_items_speakers.id
    ) AS count
    FROM cms_store_items_speakers
) a
where a.count > 0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It would probably be better to do the following, though. It makes good use of the [`having`](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_having.asp) clause:

```
select
    s.id,
    s.col1,
    count(i.speaker) as count
from
    cms_store_items_speakers s
    left join cms_store_items i on
        s.id = i.speaker
group by
    s.id,
    s.col1
having
    count(i.speaker) > 0
limit 0, 30
```

Comment: First option works great, seems my earlier (now deleted comment was due to caching), thanks for the solution.

Comment: change the count(\*) to count(i.speaker), and the having count(\*) to having count(i.speaker), just future-proof the code; if the need to count zero matches arises, then just change the inner join to left join, i'll upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 16):

You can using `HAVING` clause instead:

```
...
) AS count
FROM cms_store_items_speakers
HAVING count > 0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

`HAVING` is like `WHERE` but it is able to work on columns which are computed. **Warning:** `HAVING` works by pruning results **after** the rest of the query has been run - it is not a substitute for the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about mysql, but something like this should be very possible:

```
(SELECT 
     *
FROM
(
   SELECT cms_store_items_speakers.*,
          (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM cms_store_items
           WHERE speaker = cms_store_items_speakers.id) AS 'count'
   FROM cms_store_items_speakers)
   LIMIT 0, 30
)
WHERE count > 0;
```